# Views PHP: Getting field values and generating link

Tags: views, feeds, datetime

I want to generate the RSS feed of my calendar as:

```
PHOTO (uploaded photo)

BODY

http:://www.example.com/content/the-title (Link of feed to the content page)
```

For this I use a "Global: PHP" field in the calendar view I created, entering code in "Output code".

I didn't succeed in printing the node body using:

```
<?php echo $row->body; ?>
```

With this, I get the ID.

The following gives no result:

```
<?php
$node = node_load($row->nid);
print_r($node);
?>
```

Using:

```
<?php print_r($row); ?>
```

I got:

```
stdClass Object
(
[title] => The title
[body] => 1311
[rendered_entity] => 1311
[php] => 
)
```

How to I get the real content of the body, image link (field_photo) and the content link?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using these code

```
$body = $data->_field_data['nid']['entity']->field_image['und'][0]['body'];
```

**OR**

```
$node = node_load($data->$nid);
$body = $node->body[0]['value'];
```

This may be because of the [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1140896) here

Comment: With the first, I got an empty string.
The scond gives an Internal Server Error (500): Cannot access empty property.

Comment: I did a print_r on $body. I wanted access an unexisting field, so node_load works. Thanks.